# stuck on libubuntuone1.0-cil, assembly error

Tags: ubuntu-one, 11.04, banshee, mono

After I installed Banshee, apt-get is stuck (neither installed, or uninstalled) on the libubuntuone1.0-cil package:

```
Setting up libubuntuone1.0-cil (0.3.8-0ubuntu5) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libubuntuone1.0-cil into Mono
E: installing Assembly /usr/lib/cli/ubuntuone-sharp-1.0/ubuntuone-sharp.dll failed
E: Installation of libubuntuone1.0-cil with /usr/share/cli-common/runtimes.d/mono failed
dpkg: error processing libubuntuone1.0-cil (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libubuntuone1.0-cil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the following in terminal,

`sudo apt-get install -f`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

`sudo apt-get update`

if you get any errors,post the output of those errors in a pastebin.

Also see this [**bug**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libubuntuone/+bug/688538) report.

Comment: That bug report is exactly the problem I'm having! Subscribed.  Here's my error: http://pastebin.com/arvt0YZt